# Installing rgdal using its repos on Mac

Tags: r, rgdal

I am trying to install rgdal packages. For rgdal, I tried this

> install.packages("rgdal", repos =
> "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/rgdal_1.6-6.tar.gz/")

but it did not work. Any ideas? I am using mac!

Comment: The rgdal package was archived recently. The authors encourage using the sf package instead.

Comment: Thanks! But I still can use it! Right?

Comment: Yes - but I advise you to use the sf package now since the rgdal package will not be maintained anymore and if you get into trouble, you won't get much help.

Comment: Does it mean that I need to rewrite my 1000 codes by using sf instead of rgdal?

Comment: Depends on a few factors. If you want to run the code just once, then no - install an old version of rgdal so that it works. But if you plan to use the code again and again, with new data or otherwise, I would invest the time in updating the code to use the sf package.

Comment: My code is no longer working! I just need them to be working for a few more times! How can I do that?

Comment: try `install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rgdal/rgdal_1.6-7.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source')`.